# Call function that returns href property when user clicks button Vue.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, amazon-s3, e-commerce

So, first time posting, I usually just find the answer I need by looking through similar questions but this time I'm stumped.

First off, I'm self-taught and about on par with an entry-level developer at absolute best (for reference my highest score on CodeSignal for javascript is 725).

Here is my problem:

I'm working on an SSG eCommerce website using the Nuxt.js framework. The products are digital and so they need to be fulfilled by providing a time-limited download link when a customer makes a purchase. I have the product files stored in a private amazon s3 bucket. I also have a Netlify Serverless Function that when called with a GET request, generates and returns a pre-signed URL for the file (at the moment there is only one product but ideally it should generate pre-signed URLs based on a filename sent as a JSON event body key string since more products are planned in the near future, But I can figure that out once the whole thing is working).

The website is set up to generate dynamic routes based on the user's order number so they can view their previous orders(/pages/account/orders/_id.vue). I have placed a download button, nested in an  element on this page so that each order has a button to download the files. The idea is that button press calls a function I defined in the methods object. The function makes an XMLHttpRequest to the endpoint URL of the netlify function. Netlify function returns pre-signed URL to function which returns pre-signed URL to the href property so that file can be downloaded by the user.

But no matter what I try, it fails to download the file. When the page loads it successfully calls the Netlify function and I get a response code 200 but the href property remains blank. Am I going about this the wrong way? There is clearly something I'm not understanding correctly, Any input is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code....

The download button:

```
<a
   :download=<<MY_PRODUCT_NAME>>
   :href="getmyurl()"
  >
     <BaseButton
       v-if="order.status === 'complete'"
       fit="auto"
       appearance="light"
       label="Download"
     />
 </a>
```

function that button calls:

```
  methods: {
    getmyurl() {
      let myurl = "";
      const funcurl = <<MY_NETLIFY_FUNCTION_URL>>;
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('GET', funcurl);

        xhr.send();

        xhr.onload = function() {
          if (xhr.status != 200) {
            alert(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`);
          } else { 
             myurl = xhr.response.Geturl
          };
       };
       return myurl
  },
```

Netlify function:

```
require( "dotenv" ).config();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

let s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.MY_AWS_SECRET_KEY,
    region: process.env.MY_AWS_REGION,
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
});

exports.handler = function( event, context, callback ) {
    var headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
    };
 
    if ( event.httpMethod === "OPTIONS" ) {
 
        callback(
            null,
            {
                statusCode: 200,
                headers: headers,
                body: JSON.stringify( "OK" )
            }
        );
        return;
 
    }
 
    try {
 
        var resourceKey = process.env.MY_FILE_NAME

    var getParams = {
            Bucket: process.env.MY_S3_BUCKET,
            Key: resourceKey,
            Expires: ( 60 * 60 ),
            ResponseCacheControl: "max-age=604800"
        };
 
        var getUrl = s3.getSignedUrl( "getObject", getParams );
 
        var response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                getUrl: getUrl
            })
        };
 
    } catch ( error ) {
 
        console.error( error );
 
        var response = {
            statusCode: 400,
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: "Request could not be processed."
            })
        };
 
    }
 
    callback( null, response );
 
}
```

Comment: Using `<button>` in a `<a>` tag is not good option at all.  Try using the button directly and trigger an async store action (assuming you have set up VueX/Pinia).
You are getting a blank URL because xhr even called synchronically is an async operation, meaning `getmyurl()` returns `myurl` before getting the actual response from `xhr.send()`.  
Probably the better solution here would be to use a store action that will return the URL and then redirecting the user to that URL should do the trick.

Comment: too much irrelevant text